# Multiplication issue in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

when I trying to **multiply** two ***6 digit*** numbers I got an error like this ***'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int'***. 
am alredy trying with numeric format. but I got the same issue.

**eg: select ( 4561 *    6541)**

Please give me a proper solution for this. Waiting for a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to `bigint`

```
select cast(234561 as bigint) * cast(622541 as bigint)
```

(Note your 4 digit numbers in the example worked fine for me but got the error with 6 digit numbers as you described which was resolved by the code above)

Comment: Provide your input. What you have tried and What is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Integer variable capable of storing values only between **-2,147,483,648** and **2,147,483,647**.

In your case, you are trying to multiply two six digit numbers which is (123456 * 123456) = 15241383936 (no where falls between the Integer Limit). So that's why you should go for **BIGINT** datatype using SQL Server **CAST or CONVERT** function. Always search for [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187745.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, 
select cast(234561 as numeric(10,0)) * cast(622541 as numeric(10,0))